# is a dragon like this possible in the real world

Tags: biology, genetic-engineering

is a dragon the length of 30-50 feet in length and 8 feet at the shoulders able to be created with modern technology in genetic engineering?

in the inheritance series there is a physical and mental bond between dragon and rider, is this possible and if so how?
and speaking of Dragon riders could a dragon of this scale carry a human(s)?

in the same series being bonded to a dragon the rider is given almost superhuman abilities like higher endurance, speed,strength.intelligence,etc. is this possible?

and how would someone give this dragon the same cognitive abilities as a human(as intelligent

and what would a good design be for a dragon saddle for this size that could fit up to 2 people in the saddle be? (it needs to be comfortable for long distance flights but small and light enough for fast flying

(plztry using *real-world technology* no offense to the books,or you,)

Comment: With the exception of the saddle, all your questions can be answered in the following fashion: "Yes, because magic." And, if I remember correctly, the books do discuss saddle design.

Comment: sorry i meant in today's world(srry)

Comment: Six limbs is a major, major jump in evolution, just keep that in mind.

Comment: You might want t proofread and edit for clarity. I reccomend adding the science based tag, and have a summary of your question at the bottom. Something along the lines of, with current biological know sledge, are these dragons possible? would work. You should also split this into two questions, one about the dragon and the other about the saddle.

Comment: oklet me do that

Comment: Does your dragon need to be able to fly?  Also, I would define the bonding with a rider as separate from the ability of giant lizard to be able to exist.  That's actually a rather large question in and of itself.

Comment: yes and the bond if you want can post it into another answer but please go over it

Comment: You ask several different questions. It's hard to answer all of them at once. You should focus on only one side, and consider follow-up questions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the books, this question is not directly addressed per se, but it is addressed.  The Elves got their longevity from the Dragons, and the Dragons got their civility from the Elves.  Later on, the humans joined and got some of everything.  The same bond that allowed elves to live forever was much weaker in humans and only really applied to dragon riders, and it was this bond that made them stronger.  Frost is right in what he said.  The books do discuss saddle design slightly, but only in the sense of comfort/speed.

In relation to your constraints on Shruikan, there is a bit of break from reality.  In the books, dragons only exist, as Frost put it, "because magic."  It is said that magic runs through their veins.  They are also more similar to cold-blooded creatures, such as lizards, than mammals, such as whales or bears, so their eating habits are very different.  IRL, certain cold-blooded creatures can survive for 2 or more weeks with no food, and fully mature adults can go longer if needed.  Wingspan, not counting magic, would have to be ridiculously big to be practical.  Without magic, dragons basically cease to function.  It is literally stated, that, though dragons have large wingspans, they must use magic to fly.  See *Brisingr*, where Saphira has to land and walk across the border to Du Weldenvarden because of their anti-magic barriers.